# Upload large folder of json files to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a folder that consists of 20,000 json files. 
I want to be import this into an index in elastic search. I know of the bulk API, but I'm not sure how to loop over my folder to index each json.

I've seen things on how to do --databinary with the @__.json but this seems to only work for files, not an entire folder. Maybe I am just not understanding correctly.

The jsons are of type geojson and I am on a windows machine. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried filebeat to read json files?

Comment: No, last time I tried to set something up I had a lot of problems with logstash and filebeat, so want to avoid that. I'm sure I could do a for loop over the files, just not sure best method

Comment: Could you provide an example for your json files. Each of them has one ducument?

Comment: Yes each has one document. I think I just need to do a forloop over and send it to the post request, maybe using pycurl?

Comment: check this
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110068/using-a-generated-list-of-filenames-as-argument-list-with-spaces